# Using Prefetch with Batch slows down message receipt in Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, .net-core, azureservicebus

I've set the `PrefetchCount` and am receiving a batch of messages - like this:

```
receiver.PrefetchCount = 1000;
var msgs = await receiver.ReceiveAsync(1000);
```

This is in a loop, because `ReceiveAsync` doesn't always retrieve the total number of messages that I ask for (which I understand is a know issue / by design). However, doing this actually takes longer (or at least a similar time) - than just:

```
var msgs = await receiver.ReceiveAsync(1000);
```

My understanding here was that the `PrefetchCount` would force a retrieval of 1000 messages in the background, and the batch receipt would either bring down the correct amount, or it would be faster, as the messages are already cached.

Why would using Prefetch not speed up the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are setting up the PrefetchCount it never guarantees you that it will prefetch the same number of messages at the client buffer. The actual number of the message that retrieves will depend upon the max size of the message for that SKU. In a single call currently, the max [message size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas#:%7E:text=Maximum%20message%20size%3A%20256%20KB,1%20MB%20for%20Premium%20tier.) that can be received is 1 MB for premium and 256 KB for standard.

Therefore if your average message size is 100KB and you have set the PrefetchCount to 1000 for the standard namespace. Then in that case the max number of the message that will be prefetched will be 2 (100+100 KB).

When you call ReceiveAsync method then it will first check your client buffer if there are any messages available to be consumed. If yes then it will serve the request from the client buffer else it will make the call to the service bus to retrieve the message.